# Trying To Create Human Model For Android - Need Help Bake Texture -

Tags: cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine

I finished retopology (Shrinkwrap) but i didn't do it very good, Then I used Smart UV Project to unwrap and baked it with cycles render and the results is this

[image]

Any idea how i can fix the texture thats white ? or whats causing it?

Comment: You are in materials mode. try viewing in render mode. Is that any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Normal map is set to color data. Set it to non-color data.